# How to make current thread wait for other thread response using ListenableFuture Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, web-services

I have searched stackoverflow but I could find any answer using ListenableFuture or similar things. Here is what I want to do:

I have 50 webservice APIs. I want to call them, each in a seperate thread & put their responses in a Map where the key is the URL of API & value is response. Problem is when I am giving a debugger at 'Line 1' (mentioned in the code snippet) then everything runs fine. But if there is no debugger I get a 'false' in 'Line 2' i.e the HashMap is not populated. I have tried the following:

Obviously this is happening as the current thread proceeds to execute Line 1 & 2 while the other threads are still working. But I don't know how to make the current thread  wait until other threads complete their processing.

**Another question:** If one of the API takes too much time then how can I stop waiting for it & cancel it & proceed with what I have.
I have tried the following:

```
for (final StringBuilder url : urlList) {
                final URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url.append(new AuthKeyGenerator().getKey()).toString());

                final ListenableFuture<String> response = pool.submit(new Callable<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String call() throws Exception {
                        ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(uriBuilder.build());
                        clientResource.setResponseEntityBuffering(true);
                        String response = clientResource.get(String.class);

                        return response;
                    }
                });


                Futures.addCallback(response, new FutureCallback<String>() {

                        public void onSuccess(String response) {                            
                            final UrlResponse urlResponse = new UrlResponse();
                            urlResponse.setProdResponse(response);
                            urlResponseMap.put(url.toString(), urlResponse);
                        }

                        public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
                            //logger.warn(".......sections of term failed {}", thrown);
                        }
                    }, MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor());
            }
        Set<String> set = urlResponseMap.keySet();-----------Line 1
        System.out.println("********"+ set.isEmpty());-------Line 2
```